Android Studio cannot automatically merge windows when opening a new project
I have to manually click Window -> Merge All Project Windows every time I open a new project:

I forgot what settings I made for Android Studio that caused this issue, and now I want it to be restored to its original state。
I hope it can automatically merge all open Android projects.

"Sum up the word count"—please don't do this. If you're prompted to add more detail, add more detail.

It will do automatically when Android Studio is open on Full Window
